# Delphi and PowerPoint

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

I noticed that when I install Delphi(6,7,2000,2010), I have the option to install powerpoint control(com) related the Delphi.
I hope to know, if the version of PowerPoint has any limitation.
For example, PowerPoint 97 can not open the file PowerPoint XP?

or is there a way for Delphi can open and play any version of PowerPoint file?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office controls that come with Delphi are simply wrappers for the COM objects Microsoft provides. They're just a little more polished than the wrappers you would get if you imported the COM libraries yourself.

They don't add any capabilities beyond what the version of Office you have can do. If the Powerpoint version that you have installed on your computer can open Powerpoint XP files, then so can the Powerpoint control in your program when it's running on your computer. Your customers will need to have Powerpoint installed on their computers in order to use your program.